# show 8 posts from a top 200 - last month

Tags: mysql

I have this select to show posts order by visits:

```
SELECT id, date, fotos, title FROM posts order by visits desc limit 8
```

the problem is, I want to **alternate** the most visit posts that I have **in the last month**. Show only 8 results but each time it shows 8 from a top 200, for example.

any ideas?

Comment: alternate? Alternate how?

Comment: It sounds like you want to pull eight random rows from the top 200; is that correct?

Comment: @Rogue like rand()

Comment: yeah, perfect @ChrisForrence

Comment: I didn't consider the random at the first time. Use my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id, date, fotos, title FROM posts 
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
ORDER BY visits DESC LIMIT 0,200) tmp ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,8
```

Comment: he says random 8 from top 200.

Comment: @RickJoe, no problem

Comment: I changed to `data > MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` the where part. is it correct too?

Comment: @RickJoe, no. It's not